# This is difficult for me to understand the following sentence,please

Tags: android-fragments

> If your activity allows the fragments to be removed and replaced, you
>   should add the initial fragment(s) to the activity during the
>   activity's onCreate() method.

Comment: It sounds pretty clear to me, what exactly don't you understand ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragment is just a portion of the Activity and its completely dependent on Activity. If you need fragment in the activity, just load it in onCreateMethod.